# Can I beat the levels in the original Legend of Zelda in a non-linear fasion?

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda

I'm playing through the original *Legend of Zelda* for the first time. After beating the second dungeon, I found my way to the sixth. I struggled with a deadly Wizrobe room until I realized that I wasn't on level three.

Is it possible to play through the levels out of order, successfully? Is this a good idea in terms of progression of items?

Comment: old games like that are notorious for dungeon bypass glitches, I'm sure there are a few ways...

Comment: @fbueckert You edited out my 3:<. Is that consider good etiquette?

Comment: @iananananan On stackexchange anyone can edit anyone's posts/questions, similar to a wiki (you do need some reputation though). We like to keep things a bit serious and clean in here, so it's not uncommon to see smileys, "thanks" and improper english/capitalization edited. In general this improves the quality of the network as a whole.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ignoring glitches/exploits, there is some leeway in the order that dungeons can be completed. With the exception of Dungeon 9 (you must beat the previous 8 dungeons for entrance), you do not have to complete any of the dungeons to complete another one. Some dungeons require you to retrieve items from a different dungeon to either gain access or complete it. (I have omitted **bombs** and **keys** as a requirement, but they are probably the most useful tools to make it through the dungeons)

- Dungeons 1, 2, and 3, can be completed in any order.
- Dungeon 4, requires you to get the **Raft** from dungeon 3 in order to enter.
- Dungeon 5 requires the **ladder** to complete (available from dungeon 4)
- Dungeon 6 requires the **bow** + **arrow** and **ladder** to complete.
- Dungeon 7 requires the **magic flute** to enter (from level 5), requires the **ladder** and **bait** (bought in various shops) to complete.
- Dungeon 8 requires the **candle** (bought in a shop) to enter.

Once you are inside a particular dungeon housing one of required magic items for a different dungeon, there are no required items besides bombs and keys to retrieve the item.

Now, this is not to say it is a good idea to do them out of order. The sword upgrades are only available once you get a certain number of heart containers. In order to easily kill monsters in higher numbered dungeons it is advised to complete the lower numbered dungeon so you can get a new heart container and potentially gain access to an upgraded weapon.

Comment: The items found in and required for different levels in this answer applies to the first quest (your first play through the game). During the second quest, you find the items in a different levels, but you can still complete the first 8 levels in any order.

Answer (score 0):

You weren't the only one who found out the hard way you were in a higher level dungeon by accident :D. It's true you can beat the above levels in any order, but only with the items from previous dungeons as the answer says(not sure why you NEED the candle in level 8?).

For the second quest-it's almost necessary to get items and avoid the 2nd level boss so you don't die. While the boss of the first level is the same, a multi-headed dragon is the boss of stage 2. On the first quest, he's usually easy-as you have a lot of life and at least the white sword by now. For the 2nd quest, you only get 1 heart without either a whistle/ladder/raft, so no white sword. Depending on how much item collection you do before the dungeon, you can be in for a rough fight(2 heads with something like 10 hits each to kill the boss vs 4 hits to kill you). This is one instance in the game where getting the item, getting out, then doing other stuff(whistle = 3 hearts = white sword) before you come back will make your play through much easier.